# Tips for completing this python task

Tags: python, loops

I'm very new to coding and python and would like some help with finishing this small assignment I've been given.

The requirements of the project are as follows:

- Create a Python application that will loop between 1 and 100
- The numbers are to be printed out alongside their squared value
- The app should stop when a squared value of 200 or more is reached
- Reconfigure the application to take in a user value to produce squared values up to

Currently I can create the first two points, and have some idea with allowing user input into the app. With the below being the coding.

```
# The program to find the square of all numbers present in the list
# variable to store the squared numbers
square = 1
x = 200

# List of numbers
numbers = range(1,100)
#iterate over the list
for val in numbers:
    square = val*val
    # prints the output
    print ("The square of ", val, "is", square)
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Looks like you're doing pretty well already. Loops can be interrupted with the `break` statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your question says program stops when a square value of 200 or more is reached, I'll provide my implementation:

```
#square = 1 You can comment out this line since this is redundant.
#x = 200  Even this line is redundant.

# List of numbers
numbers = range(1,100)
#iterate over the list
for val in numbers:
    square = val*val
    if square >= 200:
       exit() #I prefer exit() statement over break statement, you can decide what would suit better for you
    print ("The square of ", val, "is", square)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide an upper limit for the square. I assume the user input will be the upper limit for the squares. I would code it like this:

```
n = int(input())
i = 1
while (i*i<n):
    print(i, i*i)
    i+=1
```

Comment: I worded that poorly. It does work, but there are ways it could be improved. For example you're using a flag variable that is never changed. Think about how you could improve it a bit.

Comment: Check my comment above I was in middle of editing it after you responded.

Comment: yeah, i noticed the flag variable, but I had already typed the program. But if you say so, I'll edit...